# How to obtain a logical (T/F) result when I reach the last row of data in r?

Tags: r, boolean, logical-operators

I am looking to obtain a vector of T/F values based on whether I have reached the last row of data or not. I have attached an example data frame below.

```
df <- structure(list(A = 1:24, B = 2:25), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Here is my desired output given the provided data.

```
c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
  "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "T")
```

Would be great if this was a function similar to `is.na` such that I could include in an `ifelse` statement.

i.e.,

```r
df$new_variable <- ifelse(if.last(df) == 'T' & df$B == 25, 0, df$B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```r
1:nrow(df) == nrow(df)
```

To make it a function:

```r
is.last <- function(data) {
  1:nrow(data) == nrow(data)
}

is.last(df)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easier with `rep`

```
df$new_variable <- rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), c(nrow(df)-1, 1))
```

Or create a column of `FALSE` and assign back the last row to `TRUE`

```
df$new_variable <- FALSE
df$new_variable[nrow(df)] <- TRUE
```

---

Or if we need a matrix

```
row(df) == nrow(df)
```

Or for a single column

```
seq_along(df[[1]]) == nrow(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think options 1 & 2 work for this simple example, but I am hoping to apply it more broadly. Option 3 is close to what I'm looking for, but it ends up outputting df$new_variable as a [24,2] matrix rather than a single column as intended.

Comment: @ljh2001 You can use `seq_along(df[[1]]) == nrow(df)`

Answer (score 0):

Created a little function for myself that solves this simple example.

```
if.last <- function(x) ifelse(row(x) < nrow(x), 'F', 'T')
```

```
if.last(df)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,] "F"  "F" 
 [2,] "F"  "F" 
 [3,] "F"  "F" 
 [4,] "F"  "F" 
 [5,] "F"  "F" 
 [6,] "F"  "F" 
 [7,] "F"  "F" 
 [8,] "F"  "F" 
 [9,] "F"  "F" 
[10,] "F"  "F" 
[11,] "F"  "F" 
[12,] "F"  "F" 
[13,] "F"  "F" 
[14,] "F"  "F" 
[15,] "F"  "F" 
[16,] "F"  "F" 
[17,] "F"  "F" 
[18,] "F"  "F" 
[19,] "F"  "F" 
[20,] "F"  "F" 
[21,] "F"  "F" 
[22,] "F"  "F" 
[23,] "F"  "F" 
[24,] "T"  "T"
```

```
df$new_variable <- ifelse(if.last(df) == 'T', 0, df$B)
```

```
tail(df)
    A  B new_variable 
19 19 20             20 
20 20 21             21 
21 21 22             22 
22 22 23             23 
23 23 24             24 
24 24 25              0
```

Comment: On second thought, this one doesn't work for similar reasons as to why akrun's answer didn't quite work.

Comment: Converting logical `TRUE/FALSE` to character `"T"/"F"` will discard all beneficial features of a logical object in R.